# Bash: extract 2nd integer from test string

Tags: regex, bash, shell, grep

I have a string which can contain 2 or more integers. I am trying to extract only the 2nd integer but the following code is printing all occurences.

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST_STRING=$(echo "207 - 11 (INTERRUPT_NAME) 0xffffffff:0xffffffff")

ERROR_COUNT=$(echo $TEST_STRING | grep -o -E '[0-9]+')

echo $ERROR_COUNT
```

The output is:

```
207 11 0 0
```

Basically I would like ERROR_COUNT to be 11 for the given TEST_STRING.

Comment: try  `'[0-9]{2}`'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using bash's `=~` operator:

```
$ test_string="207 - 11 (INTERRUPT_NAME) 0xffffffff:0xffffffff"
$ [[ $test_string =~ [0-9]+[^0-9]+([0-9]+) ]] && [[ ! -z ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ]] && echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
11
```

Explained:

- `[[ $test_string =~ [0-9]+[^0-9]+([0-9]+) ]]` if `$test_string` has substring
  *integer — non-integer — integer*, the latter integer is set to variable `${BASH_REMATCH[1]}`
- `&&` and
- `[[ ! -z ${BASH_REMATCH[1]} ]]` something is actually set to the variable
- `&&` "then"
- `echo ${BASH_REMATCH[1]}` output the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST_STRING=$(echo "207 - 11 (INTERRUPT_NAME) 0xffffffff:0xffffffff")

ERROR_COUNT="$( echo "${TEST_STRING}" | awk '{print $3}' )"

echo "${ERROR_COUNT}"
```

The output is:

```
11
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is my take on it, using `read` to parse the separate variables:

```
TEST_STRING="207 - 11 (INTERRUPT_NAME) 0xffffffff:0xffffffff"
read num sep ERROR_COUNT rest <<<"$TEST_STRING"
echo ${ERROR_COUNT}
11
```

Answer (score 0):

Using an auxiliary variable:

```
TEST_STRING="207 - 11 (INTERRUPT_NAME) 0xffffffff:0xffffffff"
# Remove everything until the space in front of the 11
temp=${TEST_STRING#*- }
# Remove what comes afterwards
ERROR_COUNT=${temp%% *}
```

This assumes that the error count is preceded by `-` followed and one space, and is followed by a space.